# Consigo sacar el sueldo pero no el nombre de los dos empleados

Tags: c, string

El ejercicio consiste en hacer una estructura de tipo empleado que contenga:

- nombrempleado
- sexo
- sueldo

y que saque por pantalla el nombre de los dos empleados con mayor y menor sueldo.

La salida tiene que ser:

> Cuántos empleados tiene la empresa: 3
>
> empleado 0 : Jose  sueldo 0 : 100 sexo 0 : masc
>
> empleado 1: Alex  sueldo 1 : 200 sexo 1 : masc
>
> empleado 2 : Carlos sueldo 2 : 500 sexo : masc
>
> Carlos es el que más cobra : 500.
>
> José es el que menos cobra:100

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define N 50
typedef struct {

    char nombre[N];
    float sueldo;
    char sexo[N];

} empleado;

void cambio (char palabra [N]);

int main(){

    int n ; 
    printf("Cuantos empleados tiene la empresa:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i ; 
    empleado emp[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Nombre empleado[%d]:",i);
        fflush(stdin);          
        fgets(emp[i].nombre,N,stdin);           
        cambio( emp[i].nombre);

        printf("\nSuedo empleado[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%f",&emp[i].sueldo);
        printf("\nSexo del empleado[%d]:",i);
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(emp[i].sexo,N,stdin);cambio(  emp[i].sexo);
        printf("\n");
    }

        int mayor , menor,j;
        mayor=0;  
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            if (mayor<emp[i].sueldo){
                mayor=emp[i].sueldo;
            }           
        }
        menor = mayor;
         for (j=0;j<n  ; j++){
            if (menor>emp[j].sueldo){
                menor=emp[j].sueldo;
                 }
             }

            printf("\nEl empleado con mayor sueldo es : %d",mayor);
            printf("\nEl empleado con menor sueldo es: %d",menor);  
}

void cambio(char palabra[N]){       
    int i ; 
    for (i=0; i<N;i++){
        if (palabra [N] == '\n'){
            palabra[N]='\0';            
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Alvaro, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre nosotros y ganar tu primera medalla). Esta pregunta es interesante y se ajusta a la temática del sitio, pero podrías añadir algo más de información: ¿cuál es la salida que obtienes al ejecutar tu código? ¿Recibes algún error? Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores en el código:

**VLA**

Las *Variable Length Array* no son algo soportado por el estándar de C99. Si bien están soportadas por algunos compiladores o sus extensiones no es una característica portable y, por tanto, es algo a evitar.

¿Qué es un VLA? Es un array de tamaño fijo cuyo tamaño viene determinado por una variable, es decir su tamaño se decide en tiempo de ejecución:

```
int n ; 
printf("Cuantos empleados tiene la empresa:");
scanf("%d",&n);
empleado emp[n]; // <<--- VLA
```

La alternativa es o bien determinar un número máximo de elementos en tiempo de compilación:

```
empleado emp[N]; // Por poner un ejemplo
```

O bien usar memoria dinámica:

```
empleado *emp = (empleado*)malloc(n*sizeof(empleado));

// ...

free(emp); // Liberamos la memoria reservada
```

**Cuidado con fflush**

`fflush` ... ese gran incomprendido y extrañamente usado incluso por los que enseñan a programar. La [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) de la función dice claramente que solo debe usarse con flujos de salida:

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, **flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior).**

Así que mejor evitar eso de

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Si necesitas limpiar el buffer de entrada puedes crearte una función que elimine los caracteres sobrantes hasta el salto de línea:

```
void limpiar_entrada()
{
  for( char c = getchar(); c != '\n'; c = getchar() );
}

// ...

printf("Nombre empleado[%d]:",i);
limpiar_entrada();
fgets(emp[i].nombre,N,stdin);
```

No obstante esto te lo puedes ahorrar si no es un requisito que los nombres puedan contener espacios. En este caso puedes reemplazar `fgets` por `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s",emp[i].nombre);
```

Adicionalmente, la función `cambio` no tiene ninguna utilidad... está mal implementada (iteras de `0` a `N` pero en cada iteración usas `N` en vez de `i`) sino que además es innecesaria ya que tanto `fgets` como `scanf` finalizan la cadena de texto con `'\0'`.

Lo explicado en este punto es aplicable también para el sexo.

Y ya está, con estos sencillos cambios tu código cumplirá con su cometido, sin embargo sería interesante que siguieses algunos consejos adicionales:

**Declara las variables dentro del for**

No hay necesidad de alargar la vida de las variables más allá de lo estrictametne necesario... desde C99 es posible declarar variables directamente en el `for`:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
```

**Si no es requisito expreso, que los salarios usen enteros**

Los tipos `float` y `double` permiten almacenar numeros significativamente grandes... a costa de sacrificar precisión. En el caso de `float` la precisión es de 6 dígitos y unos 12 en el caso de `double`. El resto de dígitos puedes considerarlos basura. Esto tiene sus implicaciones:

Por poner un ejemplo, en C es posible comparar enteros directamente... cuidado con hacerlo con `float`. ¿Por qué? Porque los dígitos no representativos se van a tener en cuenta en la comparación aunque sean dígitos basura. Lo que hay que hacer en estos casos es entender que dos números son iguales si su diferencia es lo suficientemente pequeña:

```
int a, b;
if( a == b ) // ok

float c, d;
if( c == d ) // CUIDADO!!!!

if( abs(c-d) < 1e5 ) // mejor
```

Así pues, usa `int` si es posible.

**El valor mayor y el menor los puedes calcular a la vez**

No hace falta iterar la colección dos veces... con un solo bucle es suficiente. Únicamente necesitas asignarle a `menor` un número lo suficientemente grande... este valor puedes ponerlo a piñón (no recomendado) o dejar que sea la librería estándar la que te de el valor más grande posible (por lo que el salario del trabajador solo podrá ser igual o inferior).

Si además has cambiado el tipo usado para el salario a `int` podrás beneficarte de la librería `limits.h` para que diga cual es el valor más alto que se puede almacenar en el tipo `int` (no hay para `float`, lo siento):

```
#include<limits.h>

int mayor = 0;
int menor = INT_MAX;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if (mayor<emp[i].sueldo){
        mayor=emp[i].sueldo;
    }
    if (menor>emp[i].sueldo){
        menor=emp[i].sueldo;
    }
}

printf("\nEl empleado con mayor sueldo es : %d",mayor);
printf("\nEl empleado con menor sueldo es: %d",menor);
```

**Para sacar el nombre del empleado junto a su salario**

En este caso merece más la pena pasarse al plano de los punteros:

```
#include<limits.h>

empleado* mayor = emp; // por defecto el primer empleado
empleado* menor = emp; // por defecto el primer empleado
for (int i=1;i<n;i++){ // No empezamos en 0 porque ese es el que esta seleccionado por defecto
    if (mayor->sueldo<emp[i].sueldo){
        mayor = &emp[i];
    }
    if (menor->sueldo>emp[i].sueldo){
        menor = &emp[i];
    }
}

printf("\n%s tiene el mayor sueldo: %d",mayor->nombre,mayor->sueldo);
printf("\n%s tiene el menor sueldo: %d",menor->nombre,menor->sueldo);
```

Comment: muchas gracias , el programa funciona correctamente , intentaré mejorar (ya que no llevo mucho programando) con los consejos que me has dado . La parte de : sacar el nombre del empleado junto a su salario con punteros no la comprendo demasiado

Comment: @Alvaro poco a poco... que son muchas cosas

Answer (score 1):

No estás haciendo el `scanf` ni del nombre ni del sexo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define N 50
typedef struct {

    char nombre[N];
    float sueldo;
    char sexo[N];

} empleado;

void cambio (char palabra [N]);

int main(){

    int n ; 
    printf("Cuantos empleados tiene la empresa:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i ; 
    empleado emp[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Nombre empleado[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%f",&emp[i].nombre);
        fflush(stdin);          
        fgets(emp[i].nombre,N,stdin);           
        cambio( emp[i].nombre);

        printf("\nSueldo empleado[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%f",&emp[i].sueldo);
        printf("\nSexo del empleado[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%f",&emp[i].sexo);
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(emp[i].sexo,N,stdin);cambio(  emp[i].sexo);
        printf("\n");
    }

        int mayor , menor,j;
        mayor=0;  
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            if (mayor<emp[i].sueldo){
                mayor=emp[i].sueldo;
            }           
        }
        menor = mayor;
         for (j=0;j<n  ; j++){
            if (menor>emp[j].sueldo){
                menor=emp[j].sueldo;
                 }
             }

            printf("\nEl empleado con mayor sueldo es : %d",mayor);
            printf("\nEl empleado con menor sueldo es: %d",menor);  
}

void cambio(char palabra[N]){       
    int i ; 
    for (i=0; i<N;i++){
        if (palabra [N] == '\n'){
            palabra[N]='\0';            
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo he hecho pero sigue sin aparecer el nombre salen unas letras raras .    He hecho esto:                                                        
 printf("\nEl empleado con mayor sueldo es %s: %d",emp[i].nombre,mayor);  
            printf("\nEl empleado con menor sueldo es %s : %d",emp[j].nombre,menor);

Comment: Piensa que la "i" y la "j" van a tener un valor que se sale de los índices de tu array. Cuando encuentres el salario mayor y menor tendrás que guardar en otras dos variables el nombre de dichos empleados (los de mayor y menor salario). O si no guardar el índice y acceder con él a tu array emp.